# Add options to my Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have one problem. I use [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) in my page, and I would like to modify it a little. This is my example:

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple>
    <!-- -->
</select>
```

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1, 
    text: "sample_1", 
    version: "1"
},{
    id: 2, 
    text: "sample_2", 
    version: "2"    
}]

$("#mySelect").select2({
    data: data
});
```

[JSFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/c6gbbgn5/)

In this example displays the text from the downloaded JSON. But what if I wanted a to modify the search? When entering text, it appears next to a third value `version` with JSON, but if I click on value `version` will not add to `select`.

Eg. When i Search in select, my select looks like:

```
- text_1 - "version"
- text_2 - "version"
```

but if I click some option, for example `text_1`, that only adds to the select box `text_1` no `version`, that is, as far. I think that the example of [Templating](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating) shows a bit of my problem. Only when you click, for example, in Alaska flag disappears and the text remains in the select

Any suggestions how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`templateSelection`](https://select2.github.io/options.html#templateSelection) and [`templateResult`](https://select2.github.io/options.html#templateResult) you can control both the search results and the view of selected item

```
$("#mySelect").select2({
  data:data,
  templateSelection: function(val) {
    return val.text +" - " + "version" + val.version;
  },
  templateResult: function(val) {
    return val.text +" "+ val.version;
  }
});
```

Comment: This shows exactly the opposite intended effect to that I wants to get. :) Ie. When i Search, display version show in the pop-up list, but when I click the search content that don't add 'version' value to my select box

Comment: templateSelection add version to selectbox when I click "sample_1" after search options, and I've just wants to avoid this :)

Comment: So you looking for `templateResult`? With bot method, you can control the output of search and selection.

Comment: Yeah! Thank You sooooo much! :)